# json_decode deals with arrays and objects

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, json

Here's the function I created to grab Delicious recent bookmarks via cURL auth and then XML->JSON conversion:

```
<?php
// JSON URL which should be requested
$json_url = 'https://api.del.icio.us/v1/posts/recent';

$username = 'myusername';  // authentication
$password = 'mypassword';  // authentication

// Initializing curl
$ch = curl_init( $json_url );

// Configuring curl options
$options = array(
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_USERPWD => $username . ":" . $password   // authentication
);

// Setting curl options
curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );



$cache_delicious = '/BLAHBLAH/'.sha1($json_url).'.json';

    if(file_exists($cache_delicious) && filemtime($cache_delicious) > time() - 1000){
        // if a cache file newer than 1000 seconds exist, use it
        $data_delicious = file_get_contents($cache_delicious);
    } else {

        $delicious_result = simplexml_load_string(curl_exec($ch));
        $data_delicious = json_encode($delicious_result);
        file_put_contents($cache_delicious, $data_delicious);
    }

$obj = $data_delicious['post']['@attributes'];

foreach (array_slice(json_decode($data_delicious, true), 0, 5) as $obj) {
    $delicious_title = str_replace('"', '\'', $obj['description']);
    $delicious_url = htmlentities($obj['href'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
    $output = "<li><a rel=\"external nofollow\" title=\"$delicious_title\" href=\"$delicious_url\">$delicious_title</a></li>";
    echo $output;
}
?>
```

Here's the JSON if I do a print_r($data_delicious);, reduced only to one entry for readability:

```
{
   "@attributes":{
      "tag":"",
      "user":"myusername"
   },
   "post":[
      {
         "@attributes":{
            "description":"Fastweb: fibra o VDSL? Disinformazione alla porta",
            "extended":"",
            "hash":"d00d03acd6e01e9c2e899184eab35273",
            "href":"http:\/\/storify.com\/giovannibajo\/fastweb-fibra-o-vdsl",
            "private":"no",
            "shared":"yes",
            "tag":"",
            "time":"2013-06-14T10:30:08Z"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Unfortunately there's something wrong with the variables (`$delicious_title` and `$delicious_url`) in `foreach`, as I get Undefined index: description and href.

Comment: try json_decode($data_delicious, true)

Comment: Needs more `var_dump` on various variables so you *see* what's going on, not *assume*.

Comment: [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).
mixed json_decode ( string $json [, bool $assoc = false [, int $depth = 512 [, int $options = 0 ]]] )
When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

Comment: Updated question. Check the undefined index error

Comment: Asking one question and then altering it to another problem just sucks. Completely ruins the relation between the answers and the visible question.

Answer (score 0):

try to catch the error by using [json-last-error](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-last-error.php)

Answer (score 0):

If you read the [manual for json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) you can see the second parameter. If you set it to true the output will be an array. So simply use `array_slice(json_decode($data_delicious, true), 0, 5)`.

Better would be to get some error checking before hand.

```
<?php
$result = json_decode($data_delicious, true);
if (is_array($result)) {
  foreach (array_slice($result, 0, 5) as $obj) {
    $delicious_title = str_replace('"', '\'', $obj->description);
    $delicious_url = htmlentities($obj->href, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
    $output = "<li><a rel=\"external nofollow\" title=\"$delicious_title\" href=\"$delicious_url\">$delicious_title</a></li>";
    echo $output;
  }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

error clearly saying

```
your variable obj is undefined
```

try this

```
$obj_delicious = json_decode($data_delicious, true); 

foreach (array_slice($obj_delicious, 0, 5) as $obj)
    {        $delicious_title = str_replace('"', '\'', $obj['post']['@attributes']['description']);
            $delicious_url = htmlentities($obj['post']['@attributes']['href'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
            $output = "<li><a rel=\"external nofollow\" title=\"$delicious_title\" href=\"$delicious_url\">$delicious_title</a></li>";
            echo $output;
    }
        }
```

Comment: Illegal string offset '@attributes'

Comment: Yeah. $obj = $data_delicious[...] was ok instead of $obj = $obj['...']. But that at (@) isn't allowed.. :( But if I remove it I get undefined index. So there should be a way to "escape" it.

Comment: I feel you dont need that $obj before foreach, try this under your foreach loop if that works for you.

$obj['post']['@attributes']['description']

Comment: With that I get "undefined index 'post'" :o

Comment: Still, undefined index: post :P
Referring to the line of if($obj['post'])

Comment: Undefinded index "@attributes". BTW I think the line shouldn't be commented out. Because $obj needs to take the input from $data_delicious!